# Load images with lower quality in firefox or chrome

Tags: browser-addons

I'm studying in a library with 150 MegaByte of Internet bandwidth. and to optimize my using I'm using offline Gmail, ad blocker and some tools like these.

I'm looking for another plugin for **GooGle Chrome** or **Firefox** to display images in lower quality in order to using less bandwidth.

I'm really appreciated for other solutions to optimize my bandwidth usage.

*OS: KUBUNTU 12.10*

Comment: Opera has Turbo mode that compresses images and transmits them through thier servers

Answer (score 3):

Using a **local(!)** plugin to reduce image size and quality requires you to first download the large version. Thus you can not reduce bandwidth usage this way.

The only way to use less bandwidth is if:

1. Someone else downloads it all, then reduces the size and you download the smaller images. (Some networks do this when you tether a mobile phone to your desktop)
2. If the site offering the images also offers smaller images.
3. You turn off image loading in a graphical browser, or
4. You use a text only browser such as lynx, links or w3m.

---

Note that you can be  your own *somebody else* from bullet point number 1. All you need is:

- A place with no bandwidth problems / limits.
- A server to run software on.
- A [proxy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proxy_server) installation configure to pass all traffic but which reduces image size.

Note that you can also use that proxy do do other things with the images.

E.g. see this XKCD comic where the images are not reduced in site, but turned upside down.
[image]

More information on how to do that can be found [here](http://www.ex-parrot.com/pete/upside-down-ternet.html).

Comment: or he can disable images

Comment: some services like OnSpeed let you load images on lower quality, but they not free. I think it is ok if we found a free alternative to OnSpeed.com

Comment: I never heard of them before. Edited the post to include your own proxy as a solution, as well as adding the obligatory XKCD reference.

Comment: another alternative is fasTun. it has premium and free mode. (as an addon for firefox)

Comment: your 1st option can be used in logic, there is a plugin or something that detects the image's url to be load; instead of rendering that image, it will pass the url to another server which downloads the image and returns low quality image version of that orignal image. in this way the bandwidth can be saved .

Comment: JPGs if set to, have attribute of progressive file structure so there's just an issue of cutting download at specified point.

Comment: Interesting. So a plugin which does that could help (even if it only works for progressive file formats).

Comment: It amazes me that the Firefox and Opera browsers on the older phones (like Nokia 7610) had an option to choose from High-res, medium-res and low-res photos and saved a lot of the bandwidth. Now they can't do it? It's just hilarious.